# Bounded function and finite measure

Tags: measure-theory

I´m thinking about a homework excercise. I believe that it isn't true, but I can't find a counterexample:
Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ a finite measure space and $f:X\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ any function. If $\epsilon>0$, then there is a set $A\in\mathcal{A}$ such that $f|_A$ is bounded and $\mu(X\backslash A)<\epsilon$.

Intuitively, the counterexample should be a function with a no countable set of points $x$ such that $f(x)=\infty$.

I hope your help. Thankyou.

Greetings.

Comment: What if $f(p)=\infty$ for all $p\in X$?

Comment: Exactly!! However, it is a trivial counterexample, but... what other condition we can add to the hypothesis for ensure the thesis?

Comment: For a MEASURABLE  function with  $|\int f d\mu|<\infty$ with a countably additive measure with $\mu (X)<\infty$ which I believe is a theorem named after someone.

Comment: Hello!! Finally I talked with my professor and the condition that he forgot to give me is that $f$ is $\mu$-finite a.e, but with that condition, the result is very easy to prove.  Thanks for your help.